# Scala - Using complicated generics to get information of a subclass and another class - doesn't compile?

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, subclass

I am writing a program in scala that uses a framework around:

```
trait Tool[T <: Tool[T, U], U <: Settings[T]] {
  // members here
  def createSettingsFrom(settingsWithStringNames: Map[String, _]): U
}

trait Settings[T <: Tool[T, _ <: Settings[T]]
```

In Tool, T is the subclass, and U is a class that carries information for it. Each Tool can be regarded as a sort of command with parameters, and those parameters are custom for each of them.

I also have a class that extends it, along with its "information carrier":

```
object Cleanup extends Tool[Cleanup, CleanupSettings] {
  override def createSettingsFrom(settings: Map[String, _]): CleanupSettings 
    = CleanupSettings(
      settings.get("attribute1").asInstanceOf[Int]
      settings.get("attribute2").asInstanceOf[String])
}

case class CleanupSettings extends Settings[Cleanup](
  //attribute1: Int,
  //attribute2: String
  //more attributes)
```

When I attempt to compile these classes, I get the following stacktrace:

`Information:21/10/16 03:20 - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 3s 200ms
/project_folder/src/main/scala/io/oreville/maptools/operations/cleanup/Cleanup.scala
Error:(17, 24) type arguments [package.tools.operations.cleanup.Cleanup,package.tools.operations.cleanup.CleanupSettings] do not conform to trait ConfigurableTool's type parameter bounds [T <: package.tools.ConfigurableTool[T,U],U <: package.tools.params.Settings[T]]
object Cleanup extends ConfigurableTool[Cleanup, CleanupSettings] {
                       ^
/project_folder/src/main/scala/io/oreville/maptools/operations/cleanup/CleanupSettings.scala
Error:(11, 11) type arguments [package.tools.operations.cleanup.Cleanup] do not conform to trait Settings's type parameter bounds [T <: package.tools.Tool[T, _ <: package.tools.params.Settings[T]]]
  extends Settings[Cleanup]
          ^`

I also have a trait ConfigurableTool which is just an extension of Tool with some extra functionality, so it has the exact same generic signature and it just `extends Tool[T, U]`.

I tried multiple things to solve the problem including adding combinations of + and - to my generics for co- and contravariance, but it doesn't help.
I did consider using a Dynamic type for my settings, but speed is a bit of a factor. I don't even know if it would solve the problem if I did.

That's it really, I hope that you have some time to help my case, if not, thanks for reading anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wan't able to reproduce the error message you got.

There are a few typos in the code, but after cleaning them up, the only error left is in the definition of `Cleanup` which you cannot pass as a type parameter when extending a trait.

```
object Cleanup extends Tool[Cleanup.type, CleanupSettings] { ... }
```

> illegal cyclic reference involving object Cleanup

You can get around that by making it a trait, and extending it in the companion object. Here's the full code:

```
trait Tool[T <: Tool[T, U], U <: Settings[T]] {
  // members here
  def createSettingsFrom(settingsWithStringNames: Map[String, _]): U
}

trait Settings[T <: Tool[T, _ <: Settings[T]]]

trait Cleanup extends Tool[Cleanup, CleanupSettings] {
  override def createSettingsFrom(settings: Map[String, _]): CleanupSettings = CleanupSettings(
    settings.get("attribute1").asInstanceOf[Int],
    settings.get("attribute2").asInstanceOf[String])
}
object Cleanup extends Cleanup

case class CleanupSettings(
  attribute1: Int,
  attribute2: String) extends Settings[Cleanup]
```

Comment: Oh, that's very cool. I ended up removing the subclass type parameter to simplify it. I realized that referencing Cleanup is not the same as referencing its class, but that's a nice workaround for the cyclic reference. Thank you :)